# CLR20r3 DllNotFoundException in Mono project; How to check what dependencies I need?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I wrote a program in MonoDevleop and GTK#. Running the program through MonoDevelop generates no problems, however if I try to run the program outside of MD(through packaging the binaries for Windows Release x86), I get this:

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   areatest.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.4500.36382
Problem Signature 03:   4f9b440c
Problem Signature 04:   glib-sharp
Problem Signature 05:   2.12.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4a1c33d2
Problem Signature 07:   2b8
Problem Signature 08:   0
Problem Signature 09:   System.DllNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0bff
Additional Information 2:   0bff8d176610735333c3986b545525d3
Additional Information 3:   b571
Additional Information 4:   b571ae7bc62750b34b3b738a0a557539
```

I googled CLR20r3 and found very little that deals with it. I've tried uninstalling everything Mono related(MonoDevelop, Gtk# for .NET, and the Mono for Windows, Gtk# and XSP installer) and reinstalling it and I've had 0 progress with finding out what's going on. Glib-sharp is referenced in my solution. I tried opening the solution in Visual C# 2010 and got 2 warnings:

```
Warning 2 The referenced component 'Mono.CSharp' could not be found.
Warning 1 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Mono.CSharp". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I referenced Mono.CSharp and it didn't get rid of the warnings. I ran the program anyway and an exception was thrown in my main program:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
    Application.Init (); // here
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
    win.Show ();
    Application.Run ();
  }
}
```

If I published the program, the .exe still had the same problem.

What I want to do is get the program to run on any operating system. For Windows I was told that my users didn't have to install Mono, just .NET 4, but when I try running it normally it gives the crash report listed above. The only way to get my program to run that I've found is by calling

```
mono AreaTest.exe
```

in the command prompt. What can I do to get the program to run on my and other's computers through .NET 4 if on Windows, and Mono on Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: Turns out that I had to install the [GTK+ Runtime](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/) in order to run the program outside of MonoDevelop. This also allowed me to open up the project in Visual C# 2010 with little errors.

Comment: You shouldn't need that - GTK# for .NET includes the GTK+ runtime. But due to the way GTK# finds the native GTK+ libraries, things can get messed up if other apps (e.g. GIMP, Inkscape) have installed GTK+ into the system PATH.

Comment: @mhutch I actually just tried installed GTK# for .NET at my school's computers and the program worked fine, so I'm guessing because I have GIMP and Inkscape installed, that screwed up my GTK+ libraries.